We live in a hypocritical society, devoid of ethics!
We meticulously groom ourselves, applying makeup before stepping out, so that everyone admires our beauty. Yet, we feel uncomfortable if someone stares at us. If we were truly dressing up for our the sake of our own happiness, there would be no need to prepare so extensively, as we would already know that we are beautiful.
It's more of a thought that crossed my mind rather than a question which I wanted to share with my great contemporaries.
Let me know what you guys think about it.

It's a bit presumptive to say we want to appear beautiful. For many people it's enough not to appear ugly.
